# Buttonless Secure DFU Service without bonds

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm researching a device from a security perspective and it utilizes Buttonless Secure DFU Service without bonds.  Would folks agree that (let's say this is a medical device) this is not a secure configuration? While this is a convenient feature, does it pose certain security concerns, especially when implemented without proper bonding mechanisms? (e.g. Eavesdropping, MiTM, Unauthorized firmware, replay attacks, etc?)

Tested DFU without bonds to determine security concerns.

Comment: This depends on the way the device handles communication internally. It is possible to encrypt messages even if no bonding is used. Have you tried to sniff the traffic to see what's actually going on?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Interesting okay.  Yeah, when I sniff the traffic there doesn't appear to be any encryption happening.  It's a little hard to tell as the device outputs strange values that aren't super straight forward to interpret with the cadence and cycling uuid. That said, I need no encrypted handshake or mention of encryption anywhere.

Comment: Is this the Buttonless Secure DFU Service by Nordic Semiconductors?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan yes, that's correct

Comment: In that case I would not see that many possible attacks since your firmware needs to be signed. I would be unable to create a firmware package for your project. But I could enter the bootloader remotely via BLE which would stop your device from functioning for a while